# how do i get socket to accept more than one connection?

Tags: python, sockets

Currently I have a socket server that can only accept ONE connection. Any second connection, it just hangs and not do anything.

The server can get the message send from one client. I have the server to send back confirmation only for now.

server.py:

```
import socket, sys

# some vars
HOST = "localhost";
PORT = 4242;

# create the socket
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);

# bind the socket to port
server_addr = (HOST, PORT);
print >>sys.stderr, "starting server %s on port %s" % (HOST, PORT);
soc.bind(server_addr);

# check for connections
soc.listen(1);

while True:
    # wait for a connection
    connection, client_address = soc.accept();
    try:
        # since just test
        # just send back whatever server receives
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16);
            if data:
                connection.sendall(str(client_address[1]) + " said " + data);
    finally:
        connection.close();
```

client.py:

```
import socket, sys, thread

# some vars
HOST = "localhost";
PORT = 4242;

# create the socket
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);

# connect to server/port
server_addr = (HOST, PORT);
print >>sys.stderr, "connecting to %s on port %s" % (HOST, PORT);
soc.connect(server_addr);

# try to send data over
while True:
    try:
        # send the message
        msg = raw_input("Message: ");
        soc.sendall(msg);

        # check if there is response
        amt_recd = 0;
        amt_expd = len(msg);

        while amt_recd < amt_expd:
            data = soc.recv(16);
            amt_recd += len(data);
            print >>sys.stderr, data, "\n";
    finally:
        msg = '';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no exit condition from this infinite loop in the server:

```
while True:
    data = connection.recv(16)
    if data:
        connection.sendall(str(client_address[1]) + " said " + data)
```

If the client closes the connection data will be empty, but it will still continue looping.  To fix:

```
while True:
    data = connection.recv(16)
    if not data:
        break
    connection.sendall(str(client_address[1]) + " said " + data)
```

Also, even after fixing this the server can only handle one connection at a time.  If you desire to service multiple clients at once, you'll need to use `select.select` or spin off threads for each client connection.

As an aside, Python does not require semicolons at the end of statements.

Comment: i'll look into this select module. i know python doesn't need ";", i just use it because it helps me to read code easier.

Comment: ok, after seeing a few examples, i sorta get it now. basically server will have a list of read/write socket lists, then service them accordingly. is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  Also check out the `SocketServer` module that comes with Python.  You can easily write code that services each client in a thread, and the source for that module is very readable as well.